# Why is carbon tetrachloride a liquid at room temperature?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

From what I can understand, $\ce{CCl4}$ has only London dispersion forces between its molecules. However, it is still liquid at room temperature. $\ce{CCl4}$ has just five atoms, making it a relatively small molecule, so how come its intermolecular forces are strong enough for it to be a liquid at room temperature and atmospheric pressure?

Comment: It may have only 5 atoms but 4 of them chlorine so it is quite heavy.

Comment: I'm not sure why it is a surprise. Pentane, with half the molar mass and also non-polar, is a liquid. There are far more factors than just polarity to explain why things are liquids.